# I need to remap a column according to a function

Tags: excel

I have a column of data that is ordered 1-35.  This ordering repeats in the same column such that it goes 1,2,3,4... 34,35,1,2,3 etc.

I would like to remap these to another column such that the new column will go
1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3....

The problem is excel gets very confused with trying to just drag this pattern down when I do it by making the new column be something like this:

=A1,=A36,=A71,=A116,=A151,=A2,=A37... then just dragging the selected cells down.

When trying the above method for some reason it thinks it should be 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2(this is what I put in manually),10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21

It for some reason things it needs to skip some cells because when the interval ends it needs to compensate for the fact that we are 10 cells lower or something idk.  But that's what I get.

All I need is to remap the cells according to the function =AX -> B(5*(x-1)+1)

This should remap A1 to B1 A2 to B6 etc then for when X>=36 just redo the mapping so its like AX->B(5*(x-36)+2) so A36 becomes B2 and A37 becomes B7

Then I can just set 5 functions for when the first row repeats.

This is what I think I need but anything that can fit the original goal would be appreciated.

Comment: I am getting confused, first you say A1,A36,A71,... then you switch for B1,B6 which column?

Comment: and your math is off is should be 1,26,71,106,141,2,....

Comment: Sorry I meant just mapping it to another column so A1 would become B1, A2 would become B6.  Your index function and implementing it has shown me enough to figure out exactly how it should end up being though, Thank you!

Comment: I didn't even need to edit anything your code snippet just worked.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your first pattern `A1,A36,A71,A106,A141,A2,A37,...`

```
=INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*35+1-INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/5)*35*5+INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/5))
```